# Save ms chart control image as svg file using C# SVG rendering library from github

Tags: c#, svg

I have an existing windows application that creates png files using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting. I have the latest C# SVG rendering library installed from NUGET but documentation is sparse, at best.

Where can I find documentation to show how to use the same logic to produce a .svg output file?

Presumably there is something similar to:
        thisChart.SaveImage(fs, ChartImageFormat.Png);
using the svg graphics object, but how to pass the existing object to the svg and then what is the code to output the appropriate file?

Comment: how about [Making SVG Charts with Common Objects](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/43483/making-svg-charts-with-common-objects)

Comment: The charts already exist and apparently the C# Rendering library can do what I need, but a tutorial or some sample code would be nice.

Comment: **apparently**? can you show corresponding online document link?

Comment: This library is a fork of https://svg.codeplex.com/ and at least one article from that time period said it can be done with SvgNet.SvgGdi which has a SvgGraphics Class. But perhaps it was dropped, something definitive from someone who knows the project would be very helpful. https://github.com/vvvv/SVG

Comment: Then does it have anything to do with **mschart**?

Answer (score 1):

Digging into the SVG Rendering Library a bit I gave up on this approach and rewrote the app to create the charts using OxyPlot instead. OxyPlot is open source and can produce svg files.