# A way to save System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting chart image as .svg or other vector image

Tags: c#, forms, svg, charts, data-visualization

I am using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting chart control to render graphs for some data in my c# winforms application. I now need to save those graphs/charts as .svg or any other lossless vector image, so that it can be seemlessly scaled when used in report.pdf.

Any suggestions are welcome.

I have looked into SaveImage(String, ChartImageFormat), where ChartImageFormat is an enum that does not include any vector image formats. Also searched stackoverflow and similar repos for an answer and as far as I see this is actually a duplicate question ([Save ms chart control image as svg file using C# SVG rendering library from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836194/save-ms-chart-control-image-as-svg-file-using-c-sharp-svg-rendering-library-from/41266829#41266829)), but the guy quit and used oxyplot instead.

```
        chart.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All;
        string imageNameAndPath = "TempImages/Image.png";
        chart.SaveImage(imageNameAndPath, ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

In short I would like to do what the above code does but with ChartImageFormat.SVG or similar.

Edit: @TaW It seems now to me that I was not able to formulate the question correctly. To elaborate: Pictured here are two plots;

[image: chart and oxy plot]

the violet one is from mentioned win forms, the white one is from oxyplot. Both get saved into files; the first one to emf the second one to svg file. Bit when those files are opened and zoomed in this is what I get:

[image: difference in vector image quality]

So now I am not sure from where this quality difference originates, but it is obvious. So I guess my question is: how would it be possible to save a chart in windows forms in a vector format of a similar quality as it is the one from Oxyplot, preferably without actually drawing on screen (somehow drawing directly to a file, so to speak)?

Comment: _where ChartImageFormat is an enum  that does not include any vector image formats._ [Look](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartimageformat?view=netframework-4.8) again! It includes versions of vector format `emf` . Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+emf) for a few discussions..

Comment: I have always found emf to work fine (if at all). What tool did you use to open and zoom? - Also: Why does your code show only the save to png?